# What's the magic key version bytes for BIP49

Tags: wallet, bip32-hd-wallets

I'm implementing BIP49-compatible key derivation for [`bitcoin-s`](https://github.com/bitcoin-s/bitcoin-s-core/), but I'm having a hard time finding the magic version bytes to use for the extended keys.

I've been looking at [BIP49](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0049.mediawiki), but can't find anything there.

Also, is there multiple schemes for deriving P2WPKH-nested-in-P2SH? I've been looking at the [Samourai fork of BitcoinJ](https://github.com/Samourai-Wallet/ExtLibJ/blob/87fcb87f87ed86c38d4b82aefac6c59ec981bdad/java/com/samourai/wallet/util/FormatsUtilGeneric.java#L30), [Trezor's implementation](https://github.com/trezor/trezor-firmware/blob/master/common/defs/bitcoin/bitcoin.json#L17) and the test vectors in BIP49, and I can't get the vectors to pass by using the magic version bytes from Trezor/Samourai.

Maybe I'm confused by which magic bytes from Samourai corresponds to mainnet/testnet P2WPKH-nested-in-P2SH, so any clarification is appreciated here. From my understanding, the mainnet version bytes are `0x049D7CB2` (pub) and `0x049D7878` (priv) and testnet are `0x044a5262` (pub) and `0x044a4e28` (priv).

As a final thing, any pointers to test vectors for BIP49 and BIP84 is appreciated. Currently I've come across the BIPs themselves, as well as [SLIP132](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0132.md#bitcoin-test-vectors).

Comment: It's always a good practice to post multiple questions separately, so that people who know one but not the other can help you out. For example, I do not have the document for test vectors handy but I have tried to answer other questions. I'll edit my answer if and when I get the test vectors.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm implementing BIP49-compatible key derivation for bitcoin-s, but I'm having a hard time finding the magic version bytes to use for the extended keys.

It's prefixes are: `YPUB = 0x049D7CB2` and `YPRV = 0x049D7878`

> Is there multiple schemes for deriving P2WPKH-nested-in-P2SH?

You are confusing the two. `77429938` that you have linked in Trezor is used to derive `ypub`. If you scroll down on Samourai code you will see `0x049D7CB2` for `ypub` which is same as `77429938` in decimal. `xpub` stands for `extended public key` and allows you to generate addresses and scan all the funds associated with them, but not spend them. `ypub` is exactly like an `xpub`, except the 'Y' denotes with certainty that this particular extended public key belongs to a wallet that is also following the BIP49 bitcoin standard. This instructs the wallet to definitely scan for P2SH(P2WPKH) addresses. There is also `zpub`, and that instructs the wallet to only scan for `bech32` addresses that starts with `bc`.

Comment: I'm aware of what an `xpub` is. The reason I'm asking if there are multiple schemes is that I can't get the tests from BIP49 to line up with the values found in the Trezor and Samourai code. If I use the magic key version bytes from Trezor and Samourai I end up with xprivs that begin with `uprv`, whereas the BIP49 test vector says I should get a `tprv`. (making it look like the BIP author just used normal non-segwit testnet bytes)

Comment: @torkel `tpriv` and `upriv` are for testnet. In https://github.com/trezor/trezor-firmware/blob/master/common/defs/bitcoin/bitcoin.json#L17 the magic numbers listed are for xpriv_magic, xpub_magic, xpub_magic_segwit_p2sh(same as ypub) and xpub_magic_segwit_native(same as zpub)

Comment: @ugam-kamet I'm aware that `tprv` and `uprv` are for testnet. The issue here is that the values from Trezor and Samourai produce `uprv` keys, whereas the BIP produce `tprv` keys. That's why I'm asking if Trezor and Samourai are not BIP49-compliant, causing multiple schemes for deriving P2WPKH-nested-in-P2SH

Comment: @torkel Now I get your confusion. BIP 49 fails to change the HD seed version bytes and as a result it retains the same prefix as BIP 32 i.e. `tpriv`. Trezor and Samourai uses the `ypub` and `zpub` to clearly distinguish if they have to scan for P2SH(P2WPKH). Whatever may be the prefix, the underlying hex of private/public key is the same. So the addresses generated will also be the same. It's just encoding of the keys that is changing.

Comment: According to Trezor's blog (https://blog.trezor.io/rolling-out-trezor-wallet-segwit-segregated-witness-5700269debc5), they use BIP-49 for P2SH(P2WPKH) derivation